# How to increment an Integer field in a Kotlin Data Class

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I have a Data Class:

```
data class MyAlarmStatus(
    val notifyTimes: Int
)
```

What I would like to do invoke this data class whilst **incrementing** the Integer field simultaneously:

```
val myAlarmStatus = MyAlarmStatus(
                notifyTimes++
            )
```

However, this doesn't compile because of an **unresolved reference** on this field.  Anybody have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: `notifyTimes` must be the name of a variable if you want to use it like that.

Comment: @al3c Is it not already the name of a variable?

Comment: What value are you wanting to increment? There's nothing to increment when you're constructing the object, because it has no initial value yet. You should pass in the initial value of `notifyTimes` to the constructor. Are you wanting to create a new instance of `MyAlarmStatus` based on a previous instance of `MyAlarmStatus`, but with respective property incremented?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Integers default to zero in Kotlin and in Java when they are declared.

Comment: They do in Java. In Kotlin you *have* to specify the initial value of a property.

Comment: Are you describing something like a static local variable in C, but for the constructor? Like you want each new instance of this class to have a default value matching the last instance that was constructed, unless you increment it?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, that's it - static local variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're wanting to be able to create an incremented version of an existing instance of the class, you can give it an operator function:

```
data class MyAlarmStatus(
    val notifyTimes: Int
) {
    operator fun inc() = MyAlarmStatus(notifyTimes + 1)
}

//Usage:
var alarmStatus = MyAlarmStatus(1)
alarmStatus++ //Instantiates new instance with incremented property value and assigns it to the var
```

If you're wanting to increment some previously used value when instantiating one of these, you would need to keep it as a separate property.

```
var lastNotifyTimes = 0

var alarmStatus = MyAlarmStatus(++lastNotifyTimes)
```

Comment: It is the latter: increment some previously used value.  The only issue I see with this approach is that now I have to expose `lastNotifyTimes` as a separate variable from my Data Class to calling classes.  Makes the Data Class kinda inelegant...

Comment: You could make the primary constructor private and put the `lastNotifyTimes` in a companion object of the data class. Then create a secondary constructor with no arguments that increments `lastNotifyTimes` and uses it to call the primary constructor. But since this is a data class, the `copy` function would still be able to generate a copy with no modifications. So you'll get a compiler warning about something that doesn't matter.

Comment: To take that farther, you could make this an interface, and make the data class an implementation of the interface. Put an `invoke()` operator function in the interface's companion object that returns the implementation with an incremented value. It would look like an empty constructor you can call on the interface.

Comment: But I think this behavior is hidden and surprising so I wouldn't use it for a class that is going to be used by other people.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should initialize default value in data class.
After that try two way:

1. Create MyAlarmStatus object and try this object val myAlarmStatus = 
   MyAlarmStatus(0) and myAlarmStatus.notifyTimes =+1
2. And try as you wrote, bet set default value.

Comment: That means I have to set the default value to zero?

Comment: You should initialize when you creat object
val objectAlarm = MyAlarmStatus(0) - or any int 
probably you don't hav to initialize default value inside data class. 
just try val objectAlarm = MyAlarmStatus(0)
objectAlarm.notifyTimes =+1

Answer (score 1):

If we check this expression

```
val myAlarmStatus = MyAlarmStatus(
                notifyTimes++
            )
```

we need `notifyTimes` variable which should be reachable in this scope.

When I read this, `copy` function is the first thing coming to my mind. As it is data class:

```kotlin
var alarmStatus = alarmStatus.let{ old -> it.copy(notifyTimes= old.notifyTimes+1) }
```

Comment: We are copying the variable reference?

Comment: we don't copy the referance we copy the value of `notifyTimes` and create new instance of  `MyAlarmStatus` with new value.

Comment: I am trying to understand what is copied by `it.copy`

Comment: `copy` works like a constructor but copying all of values of the old object when you try to click `copy` function, you are directed to constructor by IntelliJIdea. Also you can check the documentation.